# ng-repeat inside of a directive not having directive functions applied to it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to basically wrap [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co) inside an angular directive. The isotope plugin is being called for .card's a, b, and c, but none of the d's. How can I get all the .card's from the ng-repeat to have the isotope directive applied to them?

```
<div id="cardHolder" isotope>
  <div class="card">a</div>
  <div class="card w2">b</div>
  <div class="card">c</div>
  <div class="card" ng-repeat="user in users">d</div>
</div>
```

directive

```
angular.module('web').directive('isotope', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, fn) {

      $(element).isotope({
        itemSelector: '.card',
        layoutMode: 'fitRows',
      });

    }
  };
});
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902596/using-isotope-with-angularjs-ng-repeat) but it doesn't seem to do anything for my situation

Comment: Could you provide your html with ng-repeat?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to format it so you could see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up a $watch (or $watchCollection in this case) on your `ng-repeat` items and have it initialize the Isotope container once the browser renders. If any new items appear in `scope.users`, have the container reload/redraw with the new items included:

```
.directive('isotope', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, fn) {
      var init;
      scope.$watchCollection('users', function(val){
        $timeout(function(){
          if(!init) {
            $(element).isotope({
              itemSelector: '.card',
              layoutMode: 'fitRows'
            });
            init = true;
          } else {
            $(element).isotope('reloadItems').isotope();
          }
        });
      });  
    }
  }
});
```

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/7pTg8XwrMKtOdTDDtI15?p=preview)

Comment: @Marc Kline You are the king man! I was searching for this for more than 8 hours today! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I am beginner with angularjs. Once I have the same issue with customSelect jquery plugin.

I have solve it using $timeout(angular's setTimeout()).

For you it will looks like this:

```
app.directive('isotope', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, fn) {
            $timeout(function() {
                $(element).isotope({
                    itemSelector: '.card',
                    layoutMode: 'fitRows'
                });
            }, 0);
        }
    };
}]);
```

I am sure that reason for such kind of behavior is scopes and reapplying problem of widget/plugin.
Isotop doesn't wait for ng-repeat.

There should be more concrete solution for this problem.
But for "fast solving" $timeout will help.